# How do I get notifications sent to each device when a child is added, using Swift and Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-realtime-database

I have a fully functioning application that uses Firebase as a backend. I want to be able to have a user receive a notification when a child is added to my Firebase database under that users ID.

I have looked everywhere but all I can find are links to **OneSignal** or people telling me to "make a custom server" as if it can be done by magic. How do I go about making a server? What language? What do I do with OneSignal? Can someone guide me step by step without telling me to simple make a custom server.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) is exactly what you're looking for. Specifically, [Realtime Database Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events):

> The Realtime Database supports the [`onWrite()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite) event, which triggers anytime data is created, destroyed, or changed in a specified database location.
>
> In a typical lifecycle, a Firebase Realtime Database function does the following:
>
> 1. Waits for changes to a particular database location for write events.
> 2. Fires when a write event occurs and performs its tasks (see [What can I do with Cloud Functions?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) for examples of use cases).
> 3. Receives an event data object that contains two snapshots of the data stored at the specified path: one with the original data prior to the change, and one with the new data.

And going through the [What can I do with Cloud Functions?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases), theres [Notifying users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens):

> **Notify users when something interesting happens**
>
> Developers can use Cloud Functions to keep users engaged and up to date with relevant information about an app. Consider, for example, an app that allows users to follow one another's activities in the app. In such an app, a function triggered by Realtime Database writes to store new followers could create Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) notifications to let the appropriate users know that they have gained new followers.
>
> [image]
>
> 1. The function triggers on writes to the Realtime Database path where followers are stored.
> 2. The function composes a message to send via FCM.
> 3. FCM sends the notification message to the user's device.
>
> To review working code, see [Send FCM notifications](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).
>
> *Other interesting notification use cases*
>
> - Send confirmation emails to users subscribing/unsubscribing to a newsletter.
> - Send a welcome email when a user completes signup.
> - Send an SMS confirmation when a user creates a new account.